# onDestroy fired instead of onPause

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onpause, ondestroy

In my app, I am checking the event `onDestroy` of my Activity where I will `cancel()` my toast display. However I pressed the `Android Home` and my app is still running in background but in my log it triggered the `onDestroy` of my activity.

From what I read, as long as the activity is not closed, the state would be `onPause` but this time it seems that going to `Android Home` will trigger `onDestroy`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In the android documentation, it says:

*`onPause()` is called when, for example, a dialog pops up (i.e. when the activity is still visible in background). However, if there is not more memory available `onStop()` might be called.

*`onStop()` is called when you press the Home button, Back-button, or launch another activity that entirely covers the initial one.

**However, if there is no more memory available, the system will call `onDestroy()`, so it can free up memory.**

Comment: recommended reading http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I installed the same app in the two devices Xperia Z and LG Optimus L-05E and when I press Home button, in Xperia `onDestroy` is not triggered but triggered in LG. I applied log in `onDestroy` to trace the state.

Comment: Yes that's possible, it's device specific. For example if the home screen has a live wallpaper running it's more likely that also the `onDestory` get's called to free up some memory.

Comment: Perhaps, there are other apps running on Xperia, or there is less RAM available.